# node npm command closed command prompt immediately

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I installed node using installer on windows 10
When I run the following command, the version is returned normally.

```sh
node -v
v14.15.3
```

but when I any `npm` command, the command prompt closes immediately.

```
npm -v
```

Comment: How does the prompt react when I run the command below? `call npm -v`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your short post, it feels to me that your shell is configured to exit when error occurs

for instance, if you are using bash, then you have the [`set` command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/set.1p.html). if you use `set -e`

> When this option is on, when any command fails the shell immediately shall exit

i guess that you shell is closing since `npm -v` returns non-zero exit code.

so depending on your environment\shell, will advise you to check whether `set -e` is set and whether `npm` in installed.